# react-native-navigation 1.1.45 and RN 0.43 compatibility

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am not able to setting up react-native-navigation for android version. My IOS app is working fine with same version of RNN and RN.

Help me configure for android.

Here is few important file from my app,

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.MY_APP_NAME;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.reactnativenavigation.bridge.NavigationReactPackage;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {


    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "ttapp";
    }
}
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
package com.MY_APP_NAME;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new VectorIconsPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

**/App/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.MY_APP_NAME'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-navigation')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

> Everything is working fine. App is also successfully builded. But react-native-navigation is not working.

Comment: I dont know if it'll work or not, since it is written [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android) `Make sure you are using react-native version >= 0.51`

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a white screen on the android device? It also happen to me (only while you have debugger enabled), but if you switch task you're good to go. Try to check [this issue](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2180) on the repo, maybe you could find your answers.

BTW as stated by Pritish, in the READ.ME the minimum version of RN supported is 0.48, for v2 you need version 0.51

Comment: So we can not use RNN with RN 0.43 ?

Comment: You can, but it'll be possible that you'll receive "unexpected behaviours". I'd suggest you to upgrade to RN 0.48 for RNN